# Including headers in additional header include paths

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, cross-compiling, include-path

I'm using eclipse Indigo for windows on windows 7 32-bit and a toolchain based on ARM cross compile toolchain which has the version of glibc-2.9 gcc-4.3.4. My project is currently in C but I'm willing to change it to C++ anytime if necessary; its configurations you might want to know are as follows.

In "**C/C++ build->settings**" section in project properties I gave the path "`/cygdrive/c/glibc-oabi-toolchain-arm-generic/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc`" for "**GCC C Compiler**" and "**GCC C Linker**" and "**GCC Assembler**" in their command boxes and set some miscellaneous parameters for compiler and linker. Then in the "**C/C++ build->Tool Chain Editor**" section the "**Current builder**" is set to "`Gnu Make Builder`" and the "**Current toolchain**" is set to "`Linux GCC`".

Now the issue is I don't seem to be able to set additional include paths properly since although I've added a path like "`c:\sdk\include`" in "**C/C++ build->settings->GCC C Compiler->Includes**" section and there's a header like "stdio.h" in that path I encounter the following error

```
unresolved inclusion:<stdio.h>
```

for following line of code

`#include <stdio.h>;`

Finally if it might be of any help the miscellaneous parameters I set for compiler are "**-Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wdeclaration-after-statement -fsigned-char -marm -mapcs -march=armv5te -mtune=arm9tdmi -mno-sched-prolog -mabi=apcs-gnu -mlittle-endian -mno-thumb-interwork -msoft-float -c**" and for linker are "**-marm -mapcs -march=armv5te -mtune=arm9tdmi -mno-sched-prolog -mabi=apcs-gnu -mlittle-endian -mno-thumb-interwork -msoft-float -Wl,-Map,"${PWD}/${ProjName}.map**".

Any advise on what might be the cause of problem is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Eclipse where the include directory of your compiler is.  I think this is how you do it:

In the **Project** menu, select **Properties**. Under **C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Includes**, click the **Add…** button. Enter the full path to your compiler's include directory (the one with stdio.h). Check the "Add to all languages" box and click OK. This will allow Eclipse to find the headers provided by the compiler, such as stdio.h, which will reduce the number of warnings you see.

Comment: dude paths have already been added automatically to "C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Includes" also, I think the problem must be something with the path string format because the OS is currently a windows one!